# Controlling the visibility of div elements based upon radio button selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm relatively new to knockout and was wondering if there was a better way to control the visibility of two div elements based upon the selection of a radio button group.

What I came up with seems rather fragile and if their were additional options this solution would not scale imo.

```
<label>Total</label><input type="radio" name="toggleGraph" value="total" data-bind="checked: toggleGraph"  />
<label>Growth</label><input type="radio" name="toggleGraph" value="growth" data-bind="checked: toggleGraph"  />

<div id="total-graph" data-bind="visible: $root.toggleGraph() === 'total'">
    Total Graph Here
</div>

<div id="growth-graph" data-bind="visible: $root.toggleGraph() === 'growth'">
    Growth Graph Here
</div>



var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.toggleGraph = ko.observable('total');
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqzhL/

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem with your current approach? I don't see anything wrong with your solution and your fiddle seams to working just fine...

Comment: Ultimately, you answered my question. I honestly didn't know if this was an acceptable use of the visibility binding in the knockout world.

Comment: I cannot speak for the "knockout world" because KO is only a hobby for me and I've never used it in any real world scenario :) but I think nothing wrong how you've used the visibility binding here for this scenario. So I've just offered some "refactorings" which may simplify/reduce the duplication in your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is fine. You need an observable (`toggleGraph`) to store the selection and based on its value you can show hide your `div`.

If you want to reuse the logic when the `total` or `growth` is selected you can move the checking logic from your view to your viewmodel into computed properties:

```
<div id="total-graph" data-bind="visible: isTotalSelected">
    Total Graph Here
</div>

<div id="growth-graph" data-bind="visible: isGrowthSelected">
    Growth Graph Here
</div>

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.toggleGraph = ko.observable('total');
    self.isTotalSelected = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.toggleGraph() === 'total'
    });
    self.isGrowthSelected = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.toggleGraph() === 'growth'
    });
}
```

But if you have lots of options this solution is not scaling well because you have to create a lots of helper properties.

Or you can create a custom binding handler which does some convention based checking which compares the `div` id with the selected value:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.visibleIfIdStartsWith = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                      viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newAccessor = function () {
            return element.id.indexOf(valueAccessor()()) === 0;
        }
        ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, newAccessor, 
            allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div id="total-graph" data-bind="visibleIfIdStartsWith: toggleGraph">
    Total Graph Here</div>
<div id="growth-graph" data-bind="visibleIfIdStartsWith: toggleGraph">
    Growth Graph Here</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4FKn2/)